# Retrieve maximum value from each cell containing list of tuples in a dataframe

Tags: python, list, pandas, max

I have a pandas dataframe, df[lists] that contains both integers and strings, it has the following format:

```
0 [(a,b,89), (a,y,992), (a,t, 99), (a,m, 1028)]
1 [(b,u,855), (b,tt,934), (b, g, 69)]
2 [(c,k, 546),(c,gf,134), (c, dd, 569)]
3 [(d,zv, 546),(d,gyr,8834), (d, dds, 5693), (d, ddd, 3459)]
```

Actually characters a, b, tt etc. are longer and used the calculate hamming distance
What I want to get is maximum values in each row  and write it as df[max]:

```
0 [1028]
1 [934]
2 [569]
3 [8834]
```

And I got here by using:

```
combined = ((x, y, (5x - 3y) for x, y in combinations(df['elements'], if x != y) 
series = Series(list(g) for k, g in groupby(combined, key=itemgetter(0)))
series = df[lists]
```

and when I use:

```
from operator import itemgetter

df['lst'].apply(lambda x: [max(x, key=itemgetter(2))[-1]])
```

I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\phash\dene_2.py", line 78, in <module>
    df['similarity'].apply(lambda x: [max(x, key=itemgetter(2))[-1]])
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 2294, in apply
    mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
  File "pandas\src\inference.pyx", line 1207, in pandas.lib.map_infer (pandas\lib.c:66124)
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\phash\dene_2.py", line 78, in <lambda>
    df['similarity'].apply(lambda x: [max(x, key=itemgetter(2))[-1]])
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

Comment: I suggest that you need to improve your data structure.  This type of structure is pain in the ass to work with.

Comment: how I could do so ? I got the result in following way
combined = ((x, y, (5x - 3y) for x, y in combinations(df['elements'], if x != y)
series = Series(list(g) for k, g in groupby(combined, key=itemgetter(0)))
series = df[list]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet would be to use a not so fast `apply` variant. Assuming the column name containing `list` cells to be represented by `"lst"`, you can grab every third element present in the list of tuples and find the maximum value by comparing them. Then from the computed `tuple`, select it's last element and convert it into a single item `list`:

```
from operator import itemgetter

df['lst'].apply(lambda t: [max(t, key=itemgetter(2))[-1]])

0    [1028]
1     [934]
2     [569]
3    [8834]
Name: lst, dtype: object
```

***data used:***

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(lst=[[('a','b', 89), ('a','y', 992), ('a','t', 99), ('a','m', 1028)], 
                            [('b','u', 855), ('b','tt', 934), ('b', 'g', 69)],
                            [('c','k', 546),('c','gf', 134), ('c', 'dd', 569)], 
                            [('d','zv', 546),('d','gyr', 8834), ('d', 'dds', 5693), ('d', 'ddd', 3459)]]))
```

---

***edit:***

Since there are possibilities of presence of missing values which get mapped as `float` objects, you could filter the cells based on their type and perform iteration over them and leave the other cells unchanged:

```
df['lst'].apply(lambda t: [max(t, key=itemgetter(2))[-1] if isinstance(t, list) else t])
```

Comment: I get 'float' object is not iterable error :/ It drives me crazy I am trying to solve same issue for 5-6 hours

Comment: Can you edit your question by attaching the complete traceback?

Comment: No, I wanted you to attach the error that you were getting before `'float' object is not iterable ...` completely. Just in case, I'll edit my post to show you the dataframe used to arrive at the result.

Comment: Alright, can you do a simple - `df['similarity'].apply(lambda t: [i[2] for i in t])`  and check if that works correctly?

Comment: Are you sure all the rows are represented alike. More precisely, do all of them have the form resembling a *list of tuples* ?. If there's even a single cell which is of type `float` (could be `nan` or any floating point number), then in which case such an error would arise. Just try - `df['similarity'].map(type).value_counts()` and see if you get a float instance somehow.

Comment: oh, I think I have a NAN value somewhere, so I should eliminate them somehow?

Comment: You're welcome. Aside -  Generally it's not a good idea to store a single element `list` at every cell. It can severely dampen performance and cause unnecessary overhead problems.

Comment: Well, actually I am trying to calculate hamming distance of images, and I currently have 100.000 images... So it means too many combinations... What would be the better solution or I should ask it as a separate question?

Comment: I'm guessing it would be better working on an array level, thereby you get enough support of `numpy` / `scipy` libraries. Even `scikit-learn` for that matter.